# How to wrap my script into one function? The professional approach?

Tags: jquery

right now I'm working on a little training-code. Trying to code a semi-fixed page-element. This is my result by now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elementPosition = $("#header").offset();
    var elementHeight = $("#header").outerHeight();
    $("#header").before("<div id='placeholder' style='display:none; height:" + elementHeight + "px'></div>");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        checkAttached("#header");
    });

    function checkAttached(element) {
        var windowDepth = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowDepth >= elementPosition.top) {
            $(element).addClass("attached");
            $("#placeholder").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass("attached");
            $("#placeholder").css("display", "none");
        };
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xM3W/

The thing is, I'm not quite happy with the solution. I would like it to be a little more flexible. My goal is an independent function that allows to address various page elements. Something like this:

```
attachThis(element);
```

Right now I'm having trouble with the scroll-event. I can't have this inside a function, can I? Further I don't know a good solution for not-overwriting "elementPosition". My current solution is to define it outside the function. Not very clean.

Of course I'm not expecting you to deliver a better script, but maybe you can push me into the right direction and point out a suitable technique for me? I Would love to know how a professional would approach this task.

Comment: I'd suggest asking on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where this question would be on topic, and you might get a better overall feedback on your code.

Comment: Thank you for your link, I'll check that out! Might be perfect to help me out in the near future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just put your code in a function](http://jsfiddle.net/9tNqG/), replacing `#header` with a parameter like `element`. There is nothing in your code that is in a global scope, so there are no problems with doing this:

```
function attach(element){
    var el = $(element),
        elementPosition = el.offset(),
        elementHeight = el.outerHeight(),
        placeholder = $("<div style='display:none; height:" + elementHeight + "px'></div>");

    el.before(placeholder);
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        checkAttached(el);
    });

    function checkAttached(element) {
        var windowDepth = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowDepth >= elementPosition.top) {
            $(element).addClass("attached");
            placeholder.css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass("attached");
            placeholder.css("display", "none");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that `id` must be unique.  If this is called more than once there will be multiple `#placeholder` elements.  Not sure if this would ever need to be called twice, but it would be a problem.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Good point. Turned it into a closed over variable.

Comment: Wow, seems like I got the principle of a function/function call wrong. I thought it would run just once from top to bottom. Thats why I assumed the scroll-eventhandler wouldn't work inside of a function. So obviously it is enaugh, to call it once to keep the scroll-eventhandler running? Thank you big time!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a jquery method

```
jQuery.fn.fix = (function($){
                    return function(){
                        var selection = this,
                            elementPosition = selection.offset(),
                            elementHeight = selection.outerHeight();
                        selection.before("<div id='placeholder" + 
                                              selection.attr('id') + 
                                           "' style='display:none;    height:"+elementHeight+"px'></div>");
                        $(window).scroll(function(){
                            var windowDepth = $(window).scrollTop();
                            if (windowDepth>=elementPosition.top) {
                      selection.addClass("attached");
                              $("#placeholder").css("display", "block");
                            } else {
                              selection.removeClass("attached");
                              $("#placeholder").css("display", "none");
                         };
                      });
                    return this;
                    };
                }(jQuery));
```

and then use it like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#header").fix();
})
```